# passed managed object context is null after passing from view controller

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm trying to do a simple core data app. I have the following code in the app delegate:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface HEFTAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>{

}


@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;


@end
```

Then in the implementation

```
#import "HEFTAppDelegate.h"
#import "HEFTMasterViewController.h"
#import "HEFTTestdatabaseMasterViewController.h"
#import "HEFTData_Manager.h"

@implementation HEFTAppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        
        //ipad init
        
    } else {
        HEFTTestdatabaseMasterViewController *testDatabaseMasterViewController = [[HEFTTestdatabaseMasterViewController alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
        HEFTData_Manager *dataManager = [[HEFTData_Manager alloc]init];
        
        self.managedObjectContext = [dataManager mainObjectContext];
        
        // Pass the managed object context to the view controller.
        
        testDatabaseMasterViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext ;
        

    }
    return YES;
}
```

The HEFTData_Manager class sets up the context etc

Looking at the debugger the context appears to get set correctly in the app delegate and when the

```
testDatabaseMasterViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext ;
```

Message is issued.

However when the table view appears the HEFTTestdatabaseMasterViewController managedObjectContext is NULL

Any ideas on whats happening and pointers would be gratefully received.

### Debugger output

At:

```
testDatabaseMasterViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext ;

testDatabaseMasterViewController    HEFTTestdatabaseMasterViewController
*   0x06d74b50 UITableViewController    UITableViewController    managedObjectContext   NSManagedObjectContext *    0x06d778e0
fetchedResultsController    NSFetchedResultsController *    0x00000000
```

At:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
   // NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.managedObjectContext;
    
    NSLog(@"context : %@",self.managedObjectContext);
    
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    
    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
    
}
```

> self  HEFTTestdatabaseMasterViewController *const 0x06d705a0
> UITableViewController UITableViewController
> UIViewController  UIViewController
> _tableViewStyle   UITableViewStyle    UITableViewStylePlain
> _keyboardSupport  id  0x00000000
> _staticDataSource id  0x00000000
> _tableViewControllerFlags   managedObjectContext   NSManagedObjectContext *    0x00000000
> fetchedResultsController  NSFetchedResultsController *    0x00000000

Comment: Are you using storyboarding? I ask because you're not setting a rootViewController before you return YES in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

Comment: Yes I am. I'm using a tab bar controller to control the app. If I add something like: self.window.rootViewController = testDatabaseMasterViewController;
The app loads but the tab bar doesn't. Sorry I've just started iOS after some experience on OSX

Answer (score 1):

You should assign your `managedObjectContext` property inside the `viewDidLoad` method of the `HEFTTestdatabaseMasterViewController` class, or if that's a library file that you're not supposed to edit simply subclass it and set it in `viewDidLoad` in your custom class.

Comment: Thanks used this and it works: id appDelegate = (id)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 
    self.managedObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

Answer (score 0):

Added:

id appDelegate = (id)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 
    self.managedObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

To the viewDidLoad method of the HEFTTestDatabaseMasterVIewController

Worked and will also work in other classes that need access to the managedObjectContext